# Packaging a C++ application from dlls into exe

Tags: c++, dll, export, sdl, exe

I'm trying to send a game made with SDL2 to a friend.
I found out that Visual Studio 2013 has an option called "Multithreaded",
which basically puts all the dll's into the exe. This doesn't work
because of the SDL2.dll and glew32.dll, which means I get weird build errors.
A different approach is to put all the required dll's into the same folder,
so I now have:

```
SDL2.dll
glew32.dll
msvcp120.dll
msvcr120.dll
```

Now my friends get the error message: "the application was
unable to start correctly 0xc00007b". How can I fix this?
I opened the exe with Dependency Walker, which gave me a huge
amount of dll's, and I don't know which I need (if I need any).

Comment: ***I found out that Visual Studio 2013 has an option called "Multithreaded", which basically puts all the dll's into the exe.*** What? I really hope that if there is a feature that embeds the dlls into an exe it is not called "Multithreaded".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. make sure you and "your friend" both use the same architecture
   x86 or x64,...etc.
2. make sure that you give him the
   redistributables for VC 2013 or whatever IDE you are using.

Comment: Is it seriously necessary for him to install the redistributables? Is there no other way?

Comment: It is but only because they are not yet provided by default in windows. they will in the future, but never with the last Visual Studio version.
Even Steam pre-install redistribuable for games that needs it when you install them.
The alternative is to provide the redistribuable dlls with your own but in this case you will not benefit from potential improvements, so using the installed one might be better. Also it's a short install which you have to do only once per user and can easily be integrated into a game installer or provided inside a zip or something.